# ajax not working with laravel deployment

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a laravel app that can be found at `https://github.com/maximus1127/drive` ...the file in question is `drive/resources/views/auditor_pages/application_review.blade.php`. When i run this on my local wamp server, everything works fine. When i upload it to hostgator (paid hosting, not trying to go the free route), everything in the app works except for the ajax requests. The ajax requests even go to the same controller as other CRUD operations that are not ajax based and those other operations work fine. So i know the files are all connecting and talking to each other. can someone help me please? You can log into my app by going to driveportal.net user email "aa@aa.com" pw "password. Click "instructors" on the left, then instructor applications, then view details. This is all dummy data seeded from composer. Click the second row as the first one has altered database info which doesn't display all features.

The background check submitted/received and the "save notes" button is all ajax. But they all produce 404 errors. Can someone please help me figure out what i'm doing wrong? I recently added some middleware to my routes and maybe that's interfering but it still works well on my local server. I'm so confused.

Edit: i should also note that my headers are stored in the auditorDefault layout file.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone interested, my ajax "url1/2/3" variables did not accommodate for my new group prefixes with the auditor middleware. when i changed the routes to accommodate for that, the ajax started working.